# Is there a simple way to get and manipulate nested <div> tags with php

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

First off, I'm far from awesome with PHP - having only a basic familiarity with it, but I'm looking for a way to manipulate the contents of nested divs with php.  This is a basic site for a local non-profit food bank that will allow them to post events for their clientelle.

For example, the file I want to parse and work with has this structure (consider this the complete file though there may be more than 2 entries at any point in time):

```
<div class="event">
 <div class="eventTitle">title text</div>
 <div class="eventContent">event content</div>
</div>

<div class="event">
 <div class="eventTitle">title2</div>
 <div class="eventContent">event content2</div>
</div>
```

My thoughts are to parse it (what's the best way?), and build a multidimensional array of all div with class="event", and the nested contents of each.  However, up to this point all my attempts have ended in failure.

The point of this is allow the user (non-technical food bank admin) to add, edit, and delete these structures.  I have the code working to add the structures - but am uncertain as to how I would re-open the file at a later date to then edit and/or delete select instances of the "event" divs and their nested contents.  It seems like it should be an easy task but I just can't wrap my head around the search results I have found online.

I have tried some stuff with preg_match(), getElementById(), and getElementByTagName().  I'd really like to help this organization out but I'm at the point where I have to defer to my betters for advice on how to solve the task at hand.

Thanks in advance.

To Clarify:
This is for their website, hosted on an external service by a provider that does not allow them to host a DB or provide ftp/sftp/ssh access to the server for regular maintenance.  The plan is to get the site up there once, and from then on, have it maintained via an unsecure (no other options at this point) url.

Can anyone provide a sample php syntax to parse the above html and create a multidimensional array of the div tags? As I mentioned, I have attempted to thumb my way through it, but have been unsuccessful.  I know what I need to do, I just get lost in the syntax.

IE: this is what I've come up with to do this, but it doesn't seem to work, and I don't have a strong enough understanding of php to understand exactly why it does not.

```
    <?php 

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load('events.php');  
        $events = array();
            foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node) {  
            // looks at each <div> tag and creates an array from the other named tags below // hopefully...
                $edetails = array ( 
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('eventTitle')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('eventContent')->item(0)->nodeValue
                );
                array_push($events, $edetails);
            } 


            foreach  ($events as &$edetails) { 
            // walk through the $events array and write out the appropriate information.
                echo $edetails['title'] . "<br>";
                echo $edetails['desc'] . "<br>";
        }
print_r($events); // this is currently empty and not being populated
    ?>
```

Error:
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(): Extra content at the end of the document in /var/www/html/events.php, line: 7 in /var/www/html/test.php on line 4

Looking at this now, I realize this would never work because it is looking for tags named eventTitle and eventContent, not classes. :(

Comment: It sounds like you want to manipulate some information on the client side which has nothing to do with php. If that's the case, I'd suggest you change your question to reflect that and add javascript and jquery tags.

Comment: are you looking for an client side WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Maybe you should save dynamic information on a DB and populate the HMTL file with the data you save on that DB. Would that worked for you?

Comment: http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-web-scraping-with-php/

Comment: no, the information is all located on a web server (thus PHP) - it's for their website.   They want to be able to post events (ie: the div class=event + nested tags) so that their clients can view it online.

And yes, a DB would be nice, but they do not have access to one with their hosting plan (non profit organization, so low expense)

Comment: Are you generating the events.php, or is that being generated somewhere else?

Comment: I'm generating the events.php, so I can put whatever I need in it.

Comment: I just chose to make it an html file so it could be displayed directly on their site.  

So the contents come from html form POST data, and are written to the file in the div structure (currently)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "database", whether it's an sqlite database or a simple text file (seems sufficient for your needs), and use php scripts to manipulate that file and build the required html to manage the text/database file and display the contents.

That would be a lot easier than using DOM manipulation to add / edit / remove events.

By the way, I would probably look for a sponsor, get a decent hosting provider and use a real database...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the "php" file you have (which I think is needless complex), the reasons your current code fails are:

1) The load() method for DOMDocument is designed for XML, and expects a well formed file.  The work around for this would be to either use the loadHTMLFile() method, or to wrap everything in a parent element.

2) The looping fails as the getElementsByTagName() is looking for tags - so the outermost loop gets 6 different divs in your current example (the parent event, and the children eventTitle and eventContent)

3) The inner loops fail of course, as you're again using getElementsByTagName(). Note that the tag names are all still 'div'; what you're really trying/wanting to search on is the value of 'class' attribute.  In theory, you could work around this by putting in a lot of logic using things like hasChildNodes() and/or getAttribute().

Alternatively, you could restructure using valid XML, rather than this weird hybrid you're trying to use - if you do that, you could use DOMDocument to write out the file, as well as read it.  Probably overkill, unless you're looking to learn how to use the PHP DOM libraries and XML.

As other's have mentioned, I'd change the format of events.php into something besides a bunch of div's.  Since a database isn't an option, I'd probably go for a pipe delimited file, something like:

```
title text|event content
title2|event content2
```

The code to parse this would be much simpler, something along the lines of:

```
<?php 
    $events = array();
    $filename = 'events.txt';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $lines = file($filename);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            list($title, $desc) = explode('|', $line);
            $event = array('title'=>$title, 'desc'=>$desc);
            $events[] = $event; //better way of adding one element to an array than array_push (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)
        }
    }
    print_r($events); 
?>
```

Note that this code reads the whole file into memory, so if they have too many events or super long descriptions, this could get unwieldy, but should work fine for hundreds, even thousands, of events or so.

Comment: Ok, yea I didn't use a regular text file for this since I wasn't sure about the limitations of it.  The $desc could contain a lot of information (a page or two of text).  But there will likely be under 10 events active at any one time.  I assume this will be ok so long as none of the $desc text contains a pipe | ?

Thanks for your assistance, I'll give this a go.

Comment: As long as it doesn't contain a pipe, you should be fine.  You'll probably need to write some code to handle line breaks when saving/reading the data (i.e. line breaks, as opposed to \n or similar, in the events.txt would cause issues)